# When does RTCIceConnectionState.count get fired

Tags: webrtc

From Mozilla [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/iceConnectionState) it doesn't say anything about `RTCIceConnectionStateCount`.

Comment: there is no such event in https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/

Comment: I'm using [Flutter webrtc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webrtc)